# Is it possible to listen for an ActionListener to reach a finished condition and switch to a new ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

A previous version of my program was designed to display multiple series of magic trick images all with the same type of ActionListener. For example, when displaying all the tricks with a set time between each image, I did this by using a class called TimeListener that extends ActionListener. I make a new instance of that class and then use a Timer to tell it to fire an event every duration, where duration is a variable number of milliseconds.

```
TimeListener timeListener = new TimeListener();
Timer displayTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(duration, timeListener);
displayTimer.start();
```

The series were displayed in an order that was input by the user, and a control structure within the TimeListener determined which image to display next.

I now need to set it up so that different tricks have different ActionListeners. I'd like to set them up as follows:

```
ActionListener[] actionListeners = new ActionListener[trickSettings.length];
for(int i = 0; i < trickSettings.length; i++) {
    String pace = trickSettings[i].getPace();
    String trick = trickSettings[i].getTrick();
    if(pace.equals("Set Pace") || pace.equals("Set Pace Free Pause") || pace.equals("Set Pace Timed Pause") || pace.equals("Set Pace Subgoal Pause")) {
        actionListeners[i] = new TimeListener(trick, pace);
    }
    else if(pace.equals("Yoked Pace")) {
        actionListeners[i] = new YokedListener(trick, pace);
    }
    else if(pace.equals("Self Pace")) {
        actionListeners[i] = new SelfListener(trick, pace);
    }
}
```

However, the previous approach just ran everything from the class' constructor. If I take this new approach though I need to be able to switch which ActionListener is active. I'm pretty sure this can't be switched from the constructor. Do I need to make an ActionListener to tell when these ActionListeners are done so that it can switch to the next one? Is there a simpler way to do this?

---

**Edit**  My Solution

```
private class MasterListener {
    public void newListener() {
        for(int i = 0; i < trickSettings.length; i++) {
            if(trickSettings[i].getIsDone() == false) {
                start(trickSettings[i], 0, true);
                inBegin = true;
                mouse = new Mouse(trickSettings[i]);
                addMouseListener(mouse);
                timeListener = new TimeListener(trickSettings[i]);
                displayTimer = new Timer(trickSettings[i].getDuration(), timeListener);
                displayTimer.start();
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And I just kicked it off by creating an instance of MasterListener in the constructor and calling newListener() on it. Everytime I reach the end of a trick I just call newListener() on my MasterListener object.

Note: the start method executes a new SwingWorker for preloading images in the background.

Comment: I probably have a master/controller `ActionListener` that was used by the `Timer` on each tick of the `Timer`, I would advance a counter and notify the next listener in the list myself...

Comment: Timer was just one example, it's possible that the user will be advancing through slides at a rate controlled by user clicking or from times read from a file. That said it sounds like you think a master ActionListener is a viable option, I'd just have to figure out what to make it listen for.

Comment: So, the same principle still applies, create some kind of model, which controls the order, have some kind of concept of the current slide.  Allow for the model to accept next/prev requests and process the change internally as required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid mixing data with code, in other words, avoid "hard-coding" your data, which is what you're trying to do. Instead, I would,...

- Create a new class that holds a single Trick, its Pace, whether it is yoked or not.
- You would likely have a collection of objects of this type in the model of your program
- Use the state of the current object of this class to determine how the one single ActionListener will behave. Note that an ActionListener can call different methods depending on the state of the object.

  ---

**Edit**  Your comments / my replies

> I actually already have a Class that contains all of that information called TrickSettings. Should I make this class also contain information on how many images it has shown/if it is done? In the above code trickSettings is an array of TrickSettings.

Yes. All it needs to do is to return the `size()` of the collection of images for that trick.

> My concern with your third point, is that I don't want my ActionListener firing with the same timing for all of the tricks.

So have the timer use the timing that it obtains from the current TrickSettings object that it is iterating through. No big deal.

> For example, tricks that are paced as "Yoked Pace" read the timing from a file, or even more different are tricks that are pace "Self Pace" where the user clicks to advance them. I previously had these using a MouseAdapter class instead...

This can easily be accommodated by the logic of your program.

---

**Edit**
Glad you've got things working. Since you have a solution, I'll now post mine, one I created yesterday to test my ideas. Maybe it can give you some ideas:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerSpeedEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int BI_W = 150;
   private static final int BI_H = BI_W;
   private static final int SHOW_TRICKS_COUNT = 3;
   private List<Icon> icons;
   private Random random = new Random();
   private List<ShowTricks> showTricksList = new ArrayList<>();

   public TimerSpeedEg() {
      icons = createIcons();


      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      add(createShowTricksPanel(BI_W, BI_H, "Fast", 100, false));
      add(createShowTricksPanel(BI_W, BI_H, "Slow", 1000, false));
      add(createShowTricksPanel(BI_W, BI_H, "Self-Paced", 0, true));

   }

   private JPanel createShowTricksPanel(int w, int h, String title,
         int speed, boolean selfPaced) {
      final ShowTricks showTricks = new ShowTricks(w, h);
      TrickSettings trickSettings = new TrickSettings(speed, selfPaced);
      for (Icon icon : icons) {
         trickSettings.addIcon(icon);
      }
      showTricks.setTrickSettings(trickSettings );
      JButton showButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            showTricks.show();
         }
      });
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(showButton);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
      panel.add(showTricks.getTrickLabel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      panel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      return panel;
   }

   private List<Icon> createIcons() {
      List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<Icon>();
      String[] strings = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
            "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
      for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(strings[i], SwingConstants.CENTER);
         label.setSize(BI_W, BI_H);
         label.setOpaque(true);
         Color color = new Color(random.nextInt(127) + 127,
               random.nextInt(127) + 127, random.nextInt(127) + 127);
         Color borderColor = new Color(color.getRed() - 100,
               color.getGreen() - 100, color.getBlue() - 100);
         label.setBackground(color);
         label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(borderColor, 20));
         BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(BI_W, BI_H,
               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics g = bImg.getGraphics();
         label.paint(g);
         g.dispose();
         iconList.add(new ImageIcon(bImg));
      }
      return iconList;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TimerSpeedEg mainPanel = new TimerSpeedEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerSpeedEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ShowTricks {
   int prefW;
   int prefH;
   private JLabel trickLabel = new JLabel() {
      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
      }
   };

   public ShowTricks(int prefW, int prefH) {
      this.prefW = prefW;
      this.prefH = prefH;
   }

   private TrickSettings trickSettings;

   public JLabel getTrickLabel() {
      return trickLabel;
   }

   public void setTrickSettings(TrickSettings trickSettings) {
      this.trickSettings = trickSettings;
   }

   public void show() {
      if (trickSettings == null) {
         return;
      }
      if (trickSettings.isSelfPaced()) {
         showSelfPaced();
      } else {
         showWithTimer();
      }
   }

   private void showWithTimer() {
      Timer timer = new Timer(trickSettings.getMiliseconds(), new TimerListener());
      timer.setInitialDelay(0);
      timer.start();
   }

   private void showSelfPaced() {
      trickLabel.setIcon(trickSettings.getIcon(0));
      trickLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         private int count = 1;

         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (count < trickSettings.getSize()) {
               trickLabel.setIcon(trickSettings.getIcon(count));
               count++;
            } else {
               trickLabel.removeMouseListener(this);
            }
         }
      });
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      private int count = 0;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         if (count < trickSettings.getSize()) {
            trickLabel.setIcon(trickSettings.getIcon(count));
            count++;
         } else {
            ((Timer) evt.getSource()).stop();
         }
      }
   }
}

class TrickSettings implements Iterable<Icon> {
   private List<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<Icon>();
   private int miliseconds;
   private boolean selfPaced;

   public TrickSettings(int miliseconds, boolean selfPaced) {
      this.miliseconds = miliseconds;
      this.selfPaced = selfPaced;
   }

   public int getSize() {
      return icons.size();
   }

   public int getMiliseconds() {
      return miliseconds;
   }

   public boolean isSelfPaced() {
      return selfPaced;
   }

   @Override
   public Iterator<Icon> iterator() {
      return icons.iterator();
   }

   public Icon getIcon(int index) {
      return icons.get(index);
   }

   public void addIcon(Icon icon) {
      icons.add(icon);
   }
}
```

Comment: I actually already have a Class that contains all of that information called TrickSettings. Should I make this class also contain information on how many images it has shown/if it is done? In the above code trickSettings is an array of TrickSettings.

Comment: My concern with your third point, is that I don't want my ActionListener firing with the same timing for all of the tricks. For example, tricks that are paced as "Yoked Pace" read the timing from a file, or even more different are tricks that are pace "Self Pace" where the user clicks to advance them. I previously had these using a MouseAdapter class instead...

Comment: +1 for the help so far. I added size to my TrickSettings class and I can see how that can easily be used to determine when a trick is done. Could you explain or give pseudocode for how (and in what context - constructor, in another actionlistener etc) you would have the timer get the timing from the current TrickSettings object prior to calling the ActionListener? Sorry if I'm a little slow here, I'm still learning and I think this is the core of where I was confused in the first place.

Comment: Actually even a link in the right direction would be beneficial since I'm sure this is a pretty massive topic that's probably been discussed elsewhere... I'm just not sure what it would be called.

Comment: @sage88: for one you could create your Timer instance when it is needed and give it the proper delay based on the data held by your TrickSettings class. Juust play with the code and have fun with it.

Comment: I ended up just making a class that can manage the ActionListeners as necessary, seems to work well. It was also pretty easy, not sure why I had such a block on this. I wanted to thank you again for your advice on mixing data with code. I only wish that my previous attempt at this program had taken that into consideration (was my first Java program that wasn't homework), I've dropped from 1900 lines to about 400. This will be so much easier to maintain.

Comment: @sage88: glad you've got it working. Please see edit to answer to see my attempt to solve the issue.

Comment: Ah wow, thank you very much! I will have to spend some time looking through this to see if I can make any improvements on my existing logic.